# array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, file, warnings

i have an issue with a line for several days.

Here is my code :

```
$files = array();
$count = count(array_filter($_FILES['fichier']['name']));
echo $count;

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    array_push($files, $_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name'][$i]);
}
```

This code is in a form, but when i submit my form, i have this error message :

> Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
>   in...

This part of code works in FR version, but when i tried to copy/paste in EN version, it doesn't work.

I've tried everything, nothing happens.

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

```
var_dump(array_filter($_FILES['fichier']['name']));
```

return me this :

> NULL

when i'm trying to upload 1 or many files.

Comment: `array_filter($_FILES['fichier']['name'])` returns a string containing the file name that has been uploaded under the field `fichier`. You edit the question to elaborate your requirement, may be we could help. What is it that you cant this `$count` to be?

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: $count return me 0 everytime even if i'm uploading 1 or many files. This part of code works good in FR version, i can't understand the problem.

Comment: @u_mulder var_dump($_FILES) returns to me : array(0) { } , even if i'm uploading two files, for example

Comment: So the __real problem__ is that `$_FILES` empty. Check your form. Do you have `enctype` attribute for a form?

Comment: you're right @u_mulder , i just put a enctype attribute on my form, then i put name="file[]" on my input field for multiple files, and it works. 

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you see this error you can use this:

```
<td>{{ is_array($client->phone) ? implode($client->phone, '-') : $client->phone }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`array_filter`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function in your source needs an array as parameter, and you use a string. You should ensure that the parameter is an array. If you check for that, you should use the help of `is_array`.

Answer (score -2):

You have to check first that `$_FILES` coming as an array or not using `is_array()`

```
if(is_array($_FILES['fichier']['name'])){
    $count = count(array_filter($_FILES['fichier']['name']));
} else {
    $count = 0;
} 
echo $count;
```